# Example of a Sencha Extjs custom button UI

Tags: extjs, uibutton, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to create a custom button ui using version 4.1.3 of Sencha's Extjs SDK and I keep getting errors when trying to compile my sass file with compass. I've tried troubleshooting it myself, searching around for answers online, and posting to the Sencha forum for help and I can't seem to find an answer.

Does anyone have or know of an example file with a working custom button UI implemented? I'm sure there's just one small setting or configuration I have wrong, so comparing what I have to a sample file would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is about giving concrete answers to concrete questions, not discussing stuff. Please share your error text and your code.

Comment: True. I'll kill this post and repost the problem in detail.